# I am having trouble having my Textbox read a decimal value. It gives me a error whenever I try an decimal.Parse

Tags: c#

```
Accounts a1 = new Accounts();

int ct = c1.aArr.count;

a1 = c1.aArr.aArr[0];
//a1.display();    

//first account
acctno1.Text = a1.getAcctNo();
CidTb1.Text = a1.getCustId();
typeTb1.Text = a1.getType();
```

I get the error below:
All the strings print to my textboxes just not decimals

Is it because I am missing something or am I Parsing in wrong area?

```
decimal.Parse(balTb1.Text) = a1.getBalance(); 
Console.WriteLine("Ready to display");
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax, what are you trying to do, what is getBalance, and what is the relevance of the first snippet of code?

Comment: Sorry new to using this place; got too much flak for posting too much code last time. However, I have a getBalance which is a decimal value. The other textboxes are calling other items that are string values (getAcctNo, getCustId, getType). I am looking for the correct use in how to have a decimal value print in the textbox.

Comment: the exact error code is "the left-hand side of the assignment must be a variable, property or indexer".

Comment: decimal.Parse(balTb1.Text) = a1.getBalance(); is where the error is.

Comment: `balTb1.Text = a1.getBalance().ToString();` ? I don't mean to come across as sarcastic, I'm just wondering if that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: No its not you dont worry I wouldve posted more code. When I did balTb1.Text = a1.getBalance(); I got a error "cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string'

Comment: @NickLodde No problem, you will get better as you post more. You just need to understand that we are not over your shoulder therefore we don't know what is your program doing. You need to give us a minimal but functional code sample so that we can try it on our side or understand what is going on.

Comment: "Understand that we are not over your shoulder" - Best advice you can be given when discussing software issues. Always explain it with an understanding that only you understand what you're trying to achieve :-)

Comment: Exactly thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to show the output of `a1.getBalance()`, you *normally* don't need to parse the value to your textbox.

**But with new information given to us in the comments section**, I understand that `a1.getBalance()` probably is returning a decimal value. If you want to output it in your textbox, you need not to convert your textbox, but the returned value of your balance with `.ToString();`.

```
balTb1.Text = a1.getBalance().ToString();
```

Therefore, this **^** should work considering that you have no errors anywhere else in your code.

Comment: Dang I knew it was close, thanks for the help!